# How can I check if an element is require using Protractor in angular2?

Tags: protractor

How can I check if an element(input field or drop down list) is require using Protractor in angular 2?

```
    expect(helpers.hasClass(element(by.id('datasourceName')), 'ng-invalid')).toBe(true);
```

i'm using helper from below:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-helpers

no idea whether it's correct way or not.

Answer (score 1):

locate the input and check with the `getAttribute` method:

```
expect(inputElement.getAttribute("required")).toBe("true");
```